# How to get entity class from TABLE name (hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have one MySQL table which map "specifier" to corresponding db table.

```
MariaDB [jodo]> desc MAPPING;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| specifier     | varchar(24) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| table_name    | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have created entity for each table in my hibernate project and based on specifier, I need to access corresponding entity class.

So problem is how can I get entity class from Table name ??

Answer (score 0):

AS I understand, you have table with other table names. So, you can create Map to compare specifier with class name. Something like: Map. FIll that mapping and use it choosing right class.

Comment: hello Fireworks. I don't want class name to be entered in db like that. This will be last resort when no other proper way is out.

Comment: And what question about? Do you want create entities using database table structure?

Comment: I used hibernate tool to create entities from mysql db.

Comment: i want to access these entities class, like create object corresponding to them based on "specifier" passed to my function.

Comment: If you want dynamically create class, use reflection.

Comment: I think i am not able able to explain problem properly. I have all the entity class for each table of mysql. So there is no point of creating it dynamically. Keeping Map, (which is last resort), make code difficult to maintain. As every new specifier will force me change java code. <br>
I know that in hibernate, we can get db table name by using "getTableName". I need just reverse of it. Something like getEntityClassName.